# How to Split References Into Sections

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am creating a huge bibliography without a paper; just a bibliography. I want to use something that looks like `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. I need to split the bibliography into sections, but have no idea how to do it.

Here's what I want:

[image]

See how the numbers keep increasing, while there is a heading separating the two sections? That's what I want to do. It doesn't have to be IEEEtran, but I hope it can look kinda tight like that.

Here is some code to start with:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\refname{Student Publications}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\cite{fakes1}
\cite{fakes2}
\cite{fakes3}
\cite{fakes4}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibs}
\end{document}
```

And here's the bibs file:

```
@article{fakes1,
  title={Fake Title Number One}, 
  author={S. Fake and B. Boss},
  year={2021},
  journal={AIP Advances},
        volume={11},
        number={2}
 }

@article{fakes2,
  title={Fake Title Number Two}, 
  author={R. Fake and B. Boss},
  year={2021},
  journal={AIP Advances},
        volume={11},
        number={2}
 }

@article{fakes3,
  title={Fake Title Number Three}, 
  author={J. Blow and B. Boss},
  year={2021},
  journal={AIP Advances},
        volume={11},
        number={2}
 }

@article{fakes4,
  title={Fake Title Number Four}, 
  author={G. George and B. Boss},
  year={2021},
  journal={AIP Advances},
        volume={11},
        number={2}
 }
```

I've been thinking it has something to do with chapters, or some special package.

Comment: What are the criteria for splitting?

Comment: @Guido It should be arbitrary. Might be my person, might be by year, might be by faculty vs student.